# 座標から◯チャンクのx:□ y:△ に変換したい

Tags: c#

画像のように、例えば x=16 y=0 を チャンク1のx=0,y=0
にしたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13221504048?__ysp=44OB44Oj44Oz44Kv

Comment: あ、そういえば知恵袋のurlかくの忘れてましたw

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　もうしわけありませんが、この内容だけだと質問者さんが何をなさりたいのかよく分かりませんでした。どういった背景で、具体的に何がなさりたいのかを質問文に書いていただけませんでしょうか。タグに c# とありますがどう関係していますか？　質問文下の「編集」というところから自由に追記できますので、用語の解説などを書き足していただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

知恵袋の以下の回答で解決しました。

> ara********さん
>
> | の右側の数字を xx として
>
> チャンク番号 ＝ xx / 16
>   チャンク内のx座標 ＝ xx % 16
>
> でいいんじゃありませんか
>
> <sup>-- https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13221504048</sup>